# Retaining navigation parameter in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

There's a behavior in .NET MAUI apps that I want to fully understand.

Let's say, I pass a `Customer` object to my `CustomerProfilePage.xaml` as a navigation parameter and I use the data to display some information. From there, I go to a detail page, say, `CustomerTransactionsPage.xaml` and I pass the `Customer` object as a navigation parameter to the detail page as well.

My question is this: when I come back to `CustomerProfilePage.xaml` by hitting the back icon on `CustomerTransactionsPage.xaml`, I do NOT pass anything back to the `CustomerProfilePage.xaml` but it still has the `Customer` data.

Where exactly is this data coming from?

I assume the `CustomerProfilePage.xaml` is already in the navigation stack and I simply put `CustomerTransactionsPage.xaml` on top of that. And when I get back, .NET MAUI simply pulls the `CustomerProfilePage.xaml` from the stack and it has a built-in way of retaining parameter data passed those pages. Is this correct? If not, what exactly is happening and where does .NET MAUI get the `Customer` data from?

Comment: C# passes objects by reference.  If two pages are both referencing the same instance of a class, they will both see changes made by the other page

Comment: My question more specifically was about when the object gets discarded. Is it that for as long as a `ContentPage` remains in navigation stack its navigation parameters stay in memory? I'm trying to get a clear picture of the lifecycle of navigation parameters.

Answer (score 0):

That depends GC. Objects that are not `reachable` are marked as collectable. When the object is collected depends on the `GC`; if there is no memory pressure it might never be collected until the application ends.

It is important to note that the rule is `Object is not reachable`, not that there are no references pointing at it, which is not the same.

For more information, check document: [Garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/).